# How to have linear-gradient beneath some text?

Tags: css, z-index, gradient, linear-gradients

In my page I have few sections. I want to show linear-gradient in currently active section.

```
<div class='main_wrapper'>
     <div class='header'>
       Product
     </div>

     <div class='helper'>
       Abc dda
     </div>
    <textarea>asdadadad</textarea>
    <div class='active-section'></div>
  </div>
```

Now, if I have

```
.active-section,
.active-section2{
  border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    margin-left: 0px;

    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    height: 107px;

    background: rgb(216,216,216); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(216,216,216,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(216,216,216,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(216,216,216,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

}
```

Then this will be actually over the text, that is not needed.

Following too is not expected. This is having transparency, but this will make the text look faded.

```
.active-section2{
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(216,216,216,0.51) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(216,216,216,0.51)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(216,216,216,0.51) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsbin.com/ayimuk/2

I just want to have linear gradient in active section, height of the gradient will be 100px ( lets says ). I tried using z-index that too didn't worked.

Comment: can u draw a image for what u needed

Comment: @Adrift Salute!   That's what I wanted. You can post this as answer and I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: @mastermind see  Adrift's solution. That's what I needed.

Comment: I'm glad it helped - I reposted my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `z-index` but forgot that you can't use this property without an element also having a `position` value other than the default - `static`. Adding relative positioning will bring the text above the gradient.

http://jsbin.com/itowes/1/edit